# dom4j ignoring xmlns attributes while reading

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

I dont know why but dom4j is not load xmlns attributes such as:

> xmlns="http://webservices.example.com/servicesplatform/command/1.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Other attributes loads normally but that are just ignored. I check all attributes using attribute Iterator for all elements.

There is  example how i read this xml:

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

Document document = reader.read(file);
return document;
```

I dont have idea what can i even try. :( Any idea how can I get this attributes from xml file? :(

EDIT:
I am iterate through them like that

```
public void getAllAttributes(Element element) {


    Iterator<Attribute> attributeterator = element.attributeIterator();



    while (attributeterator.hasNext()) {
        Attribute attribute = iteratorAttribute.next();
        System.out.println(attribute.getQualifiedName() + " " + , attribute.getValue());

    }


}
```

Comment: How do you iterate through attributes ? Can you post the code where you try to find them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default namespace by

`element.getNamespace()`

All the other namespaces can be obtained with

`element.additionalNamespaces()`

Comment: It's worked but when i try get name of this namespace i got null :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dom4j 2.1.0, and the following code worked to get the default namespace:

```
document.getRootElement().getNamespaceURI()
```

It returns: `http://webservices.example.com/servicesplatform/command/1.0.0`

And you can get all the namespaces objects with:

```
document.getRootElement().additionalNamespaces()
```

Answer (score -1):

`xmlns` attributes are `Namespace's`. To read them using a `Dom4j`, you can use any of the below two methods based on your needs:

[Namespace.get(String uri)](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.4/apidocs/org/dom4j/Namespace.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)

[Namespace.get(String prefix, String uri)](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.4/apidocs/org/dom4j/Namespace.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)